# Oracle documentation on return statement

Tags: oracle, function, plsql

Where does it say that oracle function on just "return" statement returns null. For example, here is simple function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FOO RETURN NUMBER AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN;
  -- is return null the same as return?
END FOO;
```

**EDIT**

Above function won't compile like **Alex Poole** reported. Function must therefore always have return value e.g. number, date, blob, clob, varchar2 or null. It can't contain only "return". Return is therefore  in oracle not the same as return null.

What I'm really wondering is where does it state that if function has the signature of returning some datatype (number, date, varchar2, blob or clob) and its body contains "return null" statement, why is that allowed, why it can return null. I suppose this is the same as in scripting languages e.g. PHP:

```
function foo($i)
{
  if( $i > 0 )
    return $i;
  return null; // return is the same as return null. Tested in PHP.
}
```

Of course this behaviour isn't allowed in C# for example:

```
static int foo() {return null;}
Error 1 Cannot convert null to 'int' because it is a non-nullable value type
```

Comment: To your second question: `null` in oracle and `null` in PHP are not quite the same. In oracle every comparison with `null` is `false`, so `( null > 0)` and `(null == 0)` and `(null < 0)`  or the same with `(null > '0')` are all `false`. Where afaik in PHP it depends on the context, compared to the number zero `null` might evaluate to zero and the condition can become `true`.

Comment: Thinking about it again for PHP it should be like this: `( null == 0)` evaluates to `(false == false)` evaluates to `(true)`.  On the other hand `( null === 0)` should evaluate  to `false` as the data-types must match as well. Can't test at the moment. I prefer Oracles null-logic anyway ;)

Comment: That's not true in Oracle - `(null > 0)`, `(null = 0)` and `(null < 0)` all evaluate to unknown (and therefore `null`), not `false`. Boolean logic in Oracle is actually tri-valued logic - `true`, `false` and `null` - you have to remember to either cater for or remove the possibility of the null case..

Comment: What you've shown won't compile; you'll get `PLS-00503: RETURN <value> statement required for this return from function`. You can only have a simple `RETURN` with no expression [in a pipelined function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CIHCCBFJ) or a procedure. The documentation doesn't state that "return is the same as return null" because it isn't...

Comment: @AlexPoole of course you are right. Eh .. should test if function compiles first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where does it say that oracle function on just "return" statement returns null

It doesn't say that anywhere, because it isn't true. You can only have a simple `return` rather then `return <expression>` in a function if [it is pipelined](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10765/pipe_paral_tbl.htm#ADDCI4692), i.e. the data has already been returned by the pipe mechanism and the return is just to indicate that control (rather than data) should return to the caller. You can also have a plain `return` in a procedure. Your sample function would not compile - you'd get `PLS-00503: RETURN <value> statement required for this return from function` as there is no expression.

The behaviour of `return` from a function is [described in the PL/SQL subprogram documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#CIHCCBFJ), and there is more detail about [the return statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/return_statement.htm#LNPLS01340), which says of the `expression`:

> Optional when the RETURN statement is in a pipelined table function. Required when the RETURN statement is in any other function. Not allowed when the RETURN statement is in a procedure or anonymous block.
>
> The RETURN statement assigns the value of *expression* to the function identifier. Therefore, the data type of expression must be compatible with the data type in the RETURN clause of the function.

So your amended question is really asking about that last sentence; why you are allowed to assign `null` regardless of the declared return data type. But you can assign null to most data types, and as Boneist pointed out, variables of most data types are initialised to null. It's valid to have set a number variable to null. A line from earlier in that documentation page says:

> the RETURN statement assigns a specified value to the function identifier

... so effectively when you call a function the return statement is assigning whatever value your expression evaluates as to the caller's variable. (Obviously that's a simplistic view; there may be several levels of caller, and you might be calling this from plain SQL so there's no PL/SQL assignment, and the internals are probably more complicated anyway).

As long as the variable is a type that can be null, there is no violation. It isn't set out as explicitly as you were hoping for though - it's more that there is nothing saying you *can't* return null. If that were the case, it would be a restriction on the function return on top of the normal data type restrictions.

---

Going a bit off-topic, there are exceptions; if you have a data type which is [restricted to not-null values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/fundamentals.htm#LNPLS197), such as [`simple_integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/datatypes.htm#LNPLS00305), then a function returning null is valid:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FOO RETURN NUMBER AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END FOO;
/

FUNCTION FOO compiled
```

... but calling it and trying to assign the value to a constrained variable will fail:

```
declare
  n simple_integer := 0;
begin
  n := foo;
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

And if you use a constrained data type for the function declaration you can't explicitly return null:

```
create or replace FUNCTION FOO RETURN SIMPLE_INTEGER AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN NULL;
END FOO;
/

FUNCTION FOO compiled
Errors: check compiler log
```

and show_errors reveals:

```
3/10           PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
3/3            PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

You can still return an expression that *evaluates* to null, which the compiler can't catch (e.g. `RETURN 1 * NULL`), but you'd still then get errors when running it:

```
declare
  n number;
begin
  n := foo;
end;
/

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "STACKOVERFLOW.FOO", line 3
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Comment: Tested all your cases. Good trick on cheating compiler. Null value means that variable has no value. It differs from variable having value space ' '. Specially in sql where row is optional (nullable) it means like mentioned that can have no value. This is different from for example C# where int a has default value 0 (also it can't have null value, won't compile).

Comment: Null means the value is unknown, which some might argue as semantically different from having no value, perhaps *8-). But yes, different from zero or a space; Oracle treats an empty string as null too though, and booleans can even be null. I'd say C# `int` behaves like Oracle's `simple_integer` in assignment from what you showed in the question; except the Oracle type has no default, you have to assign something when it's declared, and can't let it default to null. The PHP version behaves more like `pls_integer` as it allows null. Maybe.

Comment: Just read https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/the-meaning-of-null/ - null is a representation of a value that's missing, either because we don't know it or because it doesn't apply. NULL / unknown or NULL / not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find such a statement in the documentation explicitly for functions. However, if you see in [this bit of the documentation about declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/fundamentals.htm#sthref366) that `By default, variables are initialized to NULL...`. Therefore, if you don't initialize the return value, it will automatically be NULL.

ETA: haha, I should have tested the function first, as per Alex's comment, it doesn't compile. But I think the general principle of not defining variables being null still stands elsewhere *{:-)

Comment: You'd still be doing `RETURN <expr>` though, not just `RETURN`. Not sure I really understand the question though *8-)

Comment: Indeed; I must remember to test things out before replying in future! *{;-)